# Logout in Facebook Using android fb SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

my app using android facebook sdk 3.0,after login getting some response,after that i need to signout from facebook clicking on button.

How to log-out from the session in facebook 
pls help

Comment: @justin i am using facbook sdk 3.0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should do something like this.

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}

Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

Also if you store the user token in some other way you should clear that too.

Comment: I have no Session class on the facebook sdk I'm using. what gives?. I'm using gradle to get the sdk:     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'

Comment: @feresr LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Answer (score 7):

This method will help you to logout from facebook programmatically in android

```
/**
 * Logout From Facebook 
 */
public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
        }
    } else {

        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved

    }

}
```

Comment: Where this Session come from? i mean which line i have to import to use this "Session"?